# Converting a tf.Tensor to numpy array in tf.data.Dataset.map (graph mode) in TF 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using **TF 2.0**. Apparently the map transformation is done in the graph mode (I was assuming everything will be by default in the **eager mode** in TF 2.0).

I have a `tf.Tensor` which I want to convert to a `numpy` array to use it in an augmentation function.

After creating the `dataset`, I'm using `map` transformation:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, labele))
dataset = dataset.map(random_gradient, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

and the function `random_gradient` is:

```
def random_gradient(x,
                    img_channel=0,
                    grad_range=[0.5, 1.5]):
    # the shape of input x has to be cubic, i.e. d == h == w
    intensity_grad = np.random.uniform(grad_range[0], grad_range[1], 1)[0]
    d, h, w, _ = np.shape(x)
    mask3d = np.zeros(shape=(d, h, w), dtype=np.float32)
    mask2d = np.zeros(shape=(h, w), dtype=np.float32)
    mask1d = np.linspace(1, intensity_grad, w, dtype=np.float32)
    mask2d[:] = mask1d
    mask3d[:] = mask2d
    axis = np.random.randint(1, 3)
    if axis == 1:
        # gradient along the x axis
        mask3d = np.swapaxes(mask3d, 0, 2)
    elif axis == 2:
        # gradient along the y axis
        mask3d = np.swapaxes(mask3d, 1, 2)

    x[:, :, :, img_channel] = x[:, :, :, img_channel]*mask3d
    return x
```

As you can see, the `random_gradient()` works with `numpy` arrays, but here the passed argument `x` is a `tf.Tensor`.
When I want to convert `x` to a `numpy` array inside the `random_gradient()`, with `x = x.numpy()`, it says:

`*** AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Which is because here we're not in the `eager mode`.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the `mask3d` to `tf.Tensor` and finally expanded the last dimension to again get a 4D image. This fixed my problem for now because the input `x` has just one channel.

But, the question still remains open!

```
def random_gradient(x,
                    img_channel=0,
                    grad_range=[0.5, 1.5]):
    # the shape of input x has to be cubic, i.e. d == h == w
    intensity_grad = np.random.uniform(grad_range[0], grad_range[1], 1)[0]
    d, h, w, _ = np.shape(x)
    mask3d = np.zeros(shape=(d, h, w), dtype=np.float32)
    mask2d = np.zeros(shape=(h, w), dtype=np.float32)
    mask1d = np.linspace(1, intensity_grad, w, dtype=np.float32)
    mask2d[:] = mask1d
    mask3d[:] = mask2d
    axis = np.random.randint(1, 3)
    if axis == 1:
        # gradient along the x axis
        mask3d = np.swapaxes(mask3d, 0, 2)
    elif axis == 2:
        # gradient along the y axis
        mask3d = np.swapaxes(mask3d, 1, 2)

    # 3D mask3d
    mask3d = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask3d)
    # 3D x
    x = x[:, :, :, img_channel]*mask3d
    # 4D x
    x = tf.expand_dims(x, 3)

    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to use tf.py_function inside dataset.map(). This will ensure your tensor is an Eager tensor with a .numpy() attribute.